# Set navbar below of the header in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am beginner in *ASP.Net MVC* and trying to set `navbar` below of the header section in `_Layout.cshtml` file. But after a lots of effort I am able to set it like this

[image]

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="header_top navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <ul class="shopping_grid">
                    <a href="#"><li>Join</li></a>
                    <a href="login.html"><li>Sign In</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li><span class="m_1">Shopping Bag</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;(0) &nbsp;<img src="~/Content/Images/bag.png" alt="" /></li></a>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </ul>
                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div>
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("ContactLens Store", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Which is not in correct place. Please anybody suggest me, how can I fix it under header section with exact position?

Comment: a) please explain what you consider to be the "correct" position, and b) this is almost certainly dependent on some CSS, which you haven't shared. Looks like you're using Bootstrap mainly, but there are some custom classes in there too which could be having an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add margin-top to div with class navbar like below:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="margin-top:40px">
```

Comment: After adding **margin-top**, it is showing some space at the bottom of the navbar. As I have shown it in my earlier image.